# Powershell $monitor.CurrentHorizontalResolution returns nothing

Tags: powershell

Why Powershell returns nothing (not even error) when I type this on Windows 10 Surface Pro 5:

```
$monitor = Get-Wmiobject Win32_Videocontroller
$monitor.CurrentHorizontalResolution
```

Comment: Those commands work fine for me. I suspect the issue is the video driver not building the WMI class properly when it is installed.

Comment: works for me as well.

Comment: Works for me also.

Comment: The `CIM_PCVideoController` class inherits from `Win32_VideoController` class. So can you also try querying that class like `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_PCVideoController).CurrentHorizontalResolution`. If that helps!

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh great at least it returns something : 2036! thanks :)